# How can I pass a range of numbers into a function? python

Tags: python

I want to pass this range into this function to figure out what numbers are variables of 4.

```
class calculator():
    def VariableOf4(self, num):
        if num % 4 == 0:
            print("{} is a Variable Of 4".format(num))


c = calculator()
numbers = range(0,100)
c.VariableOf4(numbers)
```

Comment: why don;t you jst send two variables? range is a class object. so basically numbers is jst a class reference, not some specific random number. If you use the random package of python, then random.randint(1,101) will provide a number between 1 to 100 to check if that number is divisible by 4!

Answer (score 2):

If the function should take an iterable, it needs to iterate over it.

```
def VariableOf4(self, nums):
    for num in nums:
        if num % 4 == 0:
            print("{} is a Variable Of 4".format(num))
```

If you don't want to change the function, you need to use a loop in the caller.

```
for i in range(0, 100):
    ass.VariableOf4(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of what you're trying to do, you can pass two parameters to the function **VariableOf4** .

```
class calculator():
def VariableOf4(self, num1,num2):
    for num in range(num1,num2)
        if num % 4 == 0:
            print("{} is a Variable Of 4".format(num))


ass = calculator()
num1=0
num2=100
ass.VariableOf4(num1,num2)
```

Comment: I believe the question is asking how to literally pass a `range()` to a function